# NSScrollView scrollbars don't respond or are disabled

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I manually build and add a NSScrollView and a sub view inside it.

1. If the subview is larger than NSScrollView than scrollbars appear but i move the scrolls nothing happen.
2. If the subview is the same size as the NSSCrollView, and i make window smaller, scrollbars don't appear.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: When you say you're building it manually, I assume you mean you're doing it in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you use `setDocumentView` or `addSubview`? If you used `addSubview`, that won't work, you need to use `setDocumentView` to set the view "scrolled" by an `NSScrollView`.

The `NSScrollView` instance will automatically lay out your view. If you'd like to override this behavior, you can subclass `NSScrollView` and override `-tile`.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon your question a month late, but for other people that have the same problem...

Apple's docs have a good solution here that worked for me: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/TextInScrollView.html

Their answer is geared towards an NSTextView, but it seems any NSView subclass should work.

```
// Create scroll view & set its properties
NSScrollView *scrollview = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[theWindow contentView] frame]];
NSSize contentSize = [scrollview contentSize];
[scrollview setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
[scrollview setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
[scrollview setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
[scrollview setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];

// Create text view and set its properties, setting content size same as scroll view
NSTextView* theTextView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, contentSize.width, contentSize.height)];
[theTextView setMinSize:NSMakeSize(0.0, contentSize.height)];
[theTextView setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];
[theTextView setVerticallyResizable:YES];
[theTextView setHorizontallyResizable:NO];
[theTextView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];
// Leave these two off if it isn't an NSTextView...
[[theTextView textContainer] setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(contentSize.width, FLT_MAX)];
[[theTextView textContainer] setWidthTracksTextView:YES];

// And connect up the view hierarchy
[scrollview setDocumentView:theTextView];
[theWindow setContentView:scrollview];
[theWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[theWindow makeFirstResponder:theTextView];
```

A lot longer than I expected, but it works. :)